# How to use REPL in sublime?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I installed REPL on sublime 2 
I'm trying to get a user input by running a sample code such as

```
puts "hello"
a = gets
```

for example.

pressing `cmd+b` just shows me the output but not prompting me for any input. what am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean you installed https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) does not work through the Build (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) system, but through a separate set of [keybindings](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#keybindings):

> - Evaluate in REPL:
>
>   - <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> Selection
>   - <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd> File
>   - <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> Lines
>   - <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> Block
> - Transfer in REPL (just copy, without evaluating it):
>
>   - <kbd>ctrl+shift+,</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> Selection
>   - <kbd>ctrl+shift+,</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd> File
>   - <kbd>ctrl+shift+,</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> Lines
>   - <kbd>ctrl+shift+,</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> Block
>
> Note: <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd> means: press Ctrl and Comma, release all, press F.

For transferring/evaluating a file, make sure that it is saved first. If you would like to see the code you transfer before it is evaluated, set `"show_transferred_text": true` in your SublimeREPL preferences - `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User`.

***NOTE*** You need to start your REPL before transferring/evaluating code.